# How do I undo copying a file that is ended up in cache?

Tags: linux, filesystems, cache, virtual-memory

I have copied a large file to USB drive.

The file appeared to be copied almost instantly, but copying operation stalled at the very end. `/proc/meminfo` is showing large, gigabyte `Dirty:` entry which is slowly decreasing, as the file is getting transferred to USD drive for real.

How do I undo and abort copying a file to thumb drive on Linux? Removing the file did not free up dirty bytes in cache - LED on the flash still blinks, as more and more data flows to now doomed file.

How do I copy a file without it excessively using cache (without going circuitous way of setting up a cgroup with a memory limit just for that one copy operation or temporarily lowering global dirty bytes limit systemwide), with userland-visible progress of copy operation being closer to actual progress?

`nocache cp` instead of `cp` still leads to seemingly instant, unabortable copy.